# No error, but program won't start on WIn 8?

Tags: vb.net, windows-8

I have written a program in VB.Net and run it for a few years on Vista and Win 7 without issue.  It is a requirements management tool front end to an Access or SQLServer backend database.

A few months ago I installed it on Win 8.  It is a 64-bit version of my program running on a 64-bit laptop.  It installs fine and runs OK initially.  However, after a few weeks it stops running.  This has happened twice, the last time after 28 days.

When I try to run the program nothing happens - no splash screen, no error message, no entry in the Applications Log in Event Viewer - just nothing happens.  The only solution has been to re-install the program and then it starts working again.

I have tried:  turning off all malware, firewall and anti-virus programs; running the program as Administrator; running in various compatibility modes.  Nothing happens.
I also tried removing the license file from the program directory.  When I did that I did get an error message in the Application Log in Event Viewer, so the program is trying to start.  But when I returned the license file it still won't start and there is no error message in the log file.

Program was written in VS 2008 under .Net framework 3.5.  I don't think this is an issue, since it runs fine for about a month after install.  Also, it is not the license file.  The license is perpetual, and anyway if it fails the license there is a splash screen that comes up, and that is not happening.

Can anyone suggest where I might look in Win 8 to try and work out what is going on when I try to start the program?

UPDATE:  Through using the Reliability Monitor I have just noticed that at 2:30pm on the afternoon of the problem Windows Installer reconfigured my application.  I had the app open all afternoon. but when I shut it at around 4:40pm, then tried to open it again, the problem above emerged.

Description
Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: Capability Architect. Product Version: 1.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: SDG. Reconfiguration success or error status: 0.

The reason for the reconfiguration was:
Detection of product '{221672D4-9B64-4550-8B8A-A13C4BE20780}', feature 'DefaultFeature', component '{4F120286-6AE1-5DFE-65E4-A4495CA3F296}' failed.  The resource 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\SDG\Capbility Architect  Template v2.0.accdb' does not exist.

Now, that file is installed by default with the product.  However, I had deleted it earlier that day because I never use it and that seems to have triggered the reconfiguration.  Is that normal behaviour??  And why should a reconfiguration stop the program from running?  And is it possible to see exactly what the reconfiguration actually did?

EXTRA UPDATE:  If this is the problem then I can't replicate it :(  I tried deleting the folder again but it has not affected program start up at all.

Thanks

Ian

Comment: please explain about this "license"; is it yours?  If it runs on Day 1 it is not a Win8 issue. sounds license or app related.

Comment: Yes, the license is mine.  But if the license expires, or is not present, the app has fixed behaviour - it pops up a message advising the user to register the app.  But none of that is happening, which is why I am considering other possibilities.  Can you suggest anywhere in Win 8 (perhaps an appropriate log file?) where I might look to see what is happening as the app tries to start?  Thanks.